# MVC Html.BeginForm shows no action in debug

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms, partial-views

I've written a Partial View in MVC for a form. I'll save you all the markup as there is a lot, but I have the following code:-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("editmenus", "menu", FormMethod.Post, new { @role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    }
```

In the source code when I hit this form, the HTML that is rendered is:-

```
<form action="" method="post" role="form" novalidate="novalidate">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="8Mb642-N-wKjBDpC2CJWKw2epsuVaNiLTaVIM5dn4JRmvhHTLz8T4TG6F6PQ7D3opZedd03KUdY6ZvlgZ84EOCfLqE485Im2o4gHZNg7gSeLDw2XwMLrctecOv703HxcINIdDrRP6i17Ob7GaAStHg2">        
</form>
```

The action is empty on the form, and it causes it to crash when I save or add data through the form. The form is currently at /Menu/EditMenu/ and as I was doing a HttpPost directly back to the same URL I wondered if this was stopping it, however changing this had no effect.

Can anyone suggest why the action might not be being brought out in the source code?

The routing for this area of the site is:-

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Menu_Default",
            "menu/{action}/{id}/{id2}/{id3}/",
            new { controller = "Menu", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, id2 = UrlParameter.Optional, id3 = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Thanks!
Mike.

Comment: What do you mean by _"causes it to crash"_ What error messages are you getting? Are you hitting the POST method?

Comment: It simply reloads the same page and clears the form data.

Comment: Can you show your route definitions

Comment: Sure, I'll tag it on above.

Comment: It's just the one route for this area of the site, quite generic, and every other form works as well.

Comment: I don't think its the issue but you can only have one parameter which is `UrlParameter.Optional` (the last one). Try removing them.

Comment: Do you have a [httpPost]editmenus method in your menu controller?